# Where did I go wrong creating a Deterministic finite automaton?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-language, finite-automata

My goal was to create a Deterministic finite automaton that handled the regular language (00010 + 1101 + 1010)* and had a parity bit at the end to make sure 0's where even.

To clarify what I mean by even parity bit, once the finite automaton loops through all possible choices, it determines if the DFA has an even amount of 0's, if there is it will add a 0 to the end of the message, else it will add a 1.

E.G. the machine will accept 000101 but not 00010/ 10110 but not 1011

I designed an M1 that's a bit complicated so i have a picture
[image: M1 diagram of (00010 + 1101 + 1010)*]

And my M2 of the language I also drew for the purpose of this question, which is meant to add a 0 if there is an odd amount of 0's and a 1 if there is an even amount of 0's at the end of every message.

[image: M2]

I have combined the two, but I'm still getting the wrong acceptance of binary strings. I believe M2 too be my problem but I'm not sure.

Please give advice as to where I'm going wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DFAs do not **add** symbols to the input string. You clearly want to **read** an input string and determine whether it is composed of a string from your given regular language **plus** a single parity bit **at the end**.

To do so, you first need to construct a new DFA that accepts strings that satisfy the above requirements, except that the last bit need not be a parity bit. But the new DFA must still **enforce** exactly one extra bit. Then you construct a second DFA that accepts only binary strings that have correct parity. Then from both DFAs you construct a DFA that accepts the intersection of both languages, and you're done.

Comment: **Yes that's a much better way of explaining what i was trying to say, thank you!**


Can you please explain the 2nd part of your answer in a bit more detail, I'm trying to get my head around it (Sorry I might have a little less brain power I've been working on this darn thing for days)

Do you mean create a DFA that satisfies (00010 +1010+1101)*(1+0) and then join that with a DFA that accepts only even 0's?

Comment: @reemq8: My statement was in response to your attempt at M2, because you are clearly not constructing a DFA that tracks the parity so far, which is probably because you are trying to think of adding symbols rather than reading the input. You have a regular language $L$. Construct a DFA that accepts a string iff it is a string in $L$ plus an extra bit (compulsory!). That would **not** be your M1, of course. Then construct a second DFA that accepts only strings with correct parity. The intersection of those two languages is exactly what you want.

Comment: Ahhhh! Ureka! That makes much more sense then what I was doing, Well! onto coffee number 5 to try this again!

Comment: @reemq8: All the best, and after you understand this method you can look at my next answer that I'm writing now.

Comment: @user2820
so is what i have below correct to what you first said?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer does not require any thinking. Here is another approach which requires some thought but is actually easier to get right (once you understand it). The idea is always to **pretend** to be a DFA and determine exactly what you need to keep track of.

In this problem the string without the parity bit breaks into chunks of 3 types. You want to keep track of which of the 3 types the current chunk is and how far along the chunk you have read, and also the parity of the number of zeros you have seen so far, at least until the very end. Instead of parity up to the current point it is simpler to remember parity up to before the current chunk.

In other words, you have two main states $S_0,S_1$, one for each parity between each chunk. You then build a sequence of states to recognize the chunk "00010". Since it has an even number of zeros, you need such a sequence from $S_0$ to $S_0$ and a separate such sequence from $S_1$ to $S_1$. Then you do chunk "1101" in the same way, but since it has an odd number of zeros, the sequences go to the opposite main state instead, namely from $S_0$ to $S_1$ and from $S_1$ to $S_0$. Lastly you do chunk "1010", but to keep it a DFA you reuse the part that recognizes the first bit. Finally, to settle the parity bit is easy, because the final state must come immediately after $S_0$ or $S_1$, and of course you expect a zero after $S_0$ and a one after $S_1$. Again, you may need to reuse some existing states to keep it a DFA.

Comment: @reemq8: I fixed this answer to use your definition of parity. My other answer does not need fixing. =)

Answer (score 0):

@user2820

So if i understand you correctly i should be joining together 
[image]

AND

[image]

Comment: Nope. Does your second machine really accept all strings with correct parity? Try small strings. Your first machine is also wrong (try strings containing two chunks) but get the easy one right first.

Comment: Oh bugger! thought I had it! haha .. getting there slowly.

Comment: The trick is always to think exactly like a DFA. To recognize strings with an even number of ones, do you need to change anything in your head when you see a zero? What about when you see a one?

Comment: I can see how M1 is incorrect, but I'm a bit confused still how M2 is incorrect. If I'm not mistaken **and I very well could be**, for my machine it doesn't really matter how many 1's there (as long as it fits within the M1 language) and this is why it can accept a Null message (which is why in M2, it can accept only a 1) So for M2, it will accept any input of 1's and 0's as long as their is even 0's.

Comment: Really sorry I didn't realize your definition of parity (which you specified in your question) is not the usual one (even number of ones). So your M2 is correct.

Comment: I SOLVED IT! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Great! If you want to, you can update your answer and I'll be glad to check. Did you understand my other answer as well? If not, I can give the description of the DFA in pseudo-code. =)

Comment: Haha you're incredibly helpful but as its due tomorrow and I still have to work out how to minimize 26 states into something prettier, I might save trying to understand your 2nd answer for a rainy day :P

Comment: 26 states sounds about right. (Some have to be combined so that you have a DFA rather than an NFA, but you may need a few extra states for the final parity bit.) I don't think there is a substantially smaller DFA. My second method also produces the same DFA, but it's easier to use once you are familiar with it. You can come back to it another time, no problem!